# BizTalk RestFul WCF service

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have been trying hard to create a WCF Restful services exposing the schema. Below are the steps I followed

1. Created a schema with three elements and promoted them and created property schema
   [image]
2. Property Schema looks like (it didnt allow me to make pass element as Sensitive information)
   [image]

build and deployed the application

3. Then using the Biztalk WCF Publishing wizard I created the Service and the Request Response Receive location.
4. Changed the App Pool of the service to the Appl pool to which the BizTalk have access.
5. In the receive location (it is not allowing me to put < in front of tags in stack overflow)
    '<'BtsHttpUrlMapping>
    '<'Operation Name="RESTServices.REST.lims" Method = "GET" Url ="/username/{username}/pass/{pass}/specimen/{specimen}" />
    '<'/BtsHttpUrlMapping>

Now when I call this service in the browser

http://localhost/RestSer/Service1.svc/username/abc/pass/abcd/specimen/J000123134

I get the below error
[image]

Please can anybody point if I am doing anything wrong here, why do I get this error? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the variable mapping? Some good resource --> http://vikasbhardwaj15.blogspot.be/2014/01/publish-rest-service-from-biztalk-server.html

Comment: I did do the variable mapping point to the property schema. I did follow Vikas Bhardwaj blog on this. I am not sure what else is missing here.