# HTTP method for a WCF Restful Service

Tags: wcf, rest, biztalk, wcf-rest, biztalk-2013

Can anybody tell me how do I give the HTTP method of the WCF RestFul service created by BizTalk Publishing wizard.The WCF service created for the schema is having three elements

[image]

I am trying to give in different ways but every time I am getting the new error when I am trying to browse them throw the browser.

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
 <Operation Name="RESTServices.REST.lims" Method = "GET" Url ="/username={username}&amp;pass={pass}&amp;specimen={specimen}" />
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

[image]

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
<Operation Name="RESTServices.REST.lims" Method = "GET" Url ="/username={username}/pass={pass}/specimen={specimen}" />
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

[image]
Can anybody please let me know how do I give the HTTP method and access the WCF service created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BizTalk RestFul WCF service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105670/biztalk-restful-wcf-service)

Comment: @Sven I am not able to find any solution to this problem. Thought I ll just ask about the HTTP method , how it needs to be.